# How to divide two numbers in adjacent cell (dynamic row)?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I created a function that when I double click a cell it asks for a name to put into a formula.

I can't figure out how to adjust the formula to change based on the active cell.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    Dim xRtn As Variant
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L4:L15")) Is Nothing Then
            cancel = True
            xRtn = Application.InputBox("Name", "Input")
            If xRtn <> False Then Target.Value = "=IFERROR(""" & xRtn & " (""&(ROUND(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+2)/ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)*10000%,2))&""%)"","""")"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

At the part after "ROUND", I want to divide the cell two columns to the right by the cell one column to the right. The VBA itself is outputting:

```
=IFERROR("Input ("&(ROUND(C1/B1*10000%,2))&"%)","")
```

It still gives the iferror.

```
If xRtn <> False Then Target.Value = "=IFERROR(""" & xRtn & " (""&(ROUND(C1/B1)*10000%,2))&""%)"","""")"
```

isn't good enough because the row changes based on the cell I double clicked.

I know the formula looks sloppy in VBA but essentially its spitting out "" because I can't figure out how to reference the cell.

Example:

```
=(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+2))/(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1))
```

If the above formula were in cell **A1** then it **should** take cell **C1** and divide it by **B1**.

Comment: If it's any help, hardcoding the cell C1 and B1 will output: "Input (100%)"

Comment: @BigBen I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: If `Target` is `A1`, then `Target.Offset(,1)` and `Target.Offset(,2)` will refer to `B1` and `C1` respectively.

Comment: @BigBen
`Target.Value = "=IFERROR(""" & xRtn & " (""&(ROUND(" & Target.Offset(, 1) & "/" & Target.Offset(, 2) & "*10000%,2))&""%)"","""")"`
Is that what you meant? Still no luck.

Comment: `Target.Offset(,1).Address` and `Target.Offset(,2).Address`. Also I would recommend `.Formula` instead of `.Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- `Target.Offset(,1).Address`
- `Target.Offset(,2).Address`

to refer to the cells one and two columns to the right, respectively.

```
Target.Formula = "=IFERROR(""" & xRtn & " (""&(ROUND(" & Target.Offset(, 1).Address & "/" & Target.Offset(, 2).Address & "*10000%,2))&""%)"","""")"
```